# Use multiple layout manager in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, jbutton

I want to place the `button` below the "898 Food Restaurant" `Jlabel`. The `setLocation()` for `button` not working.

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel{

    JLabel picLabel,title;
    JButton button;
    public MainMenu() throws IOException
    {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\seng\\workspace\\FoodOrderingSystem\\ramen-noodles.png"));
    Image scaled = myPicture.getScaledInstance(170,170,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaled)); 
    title = new JLabel("898 Food Restaurant");
    title.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD,18));
    title.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    button = new JButton("Order Food Now >>");
    button.setLocation(40,380);
    button.setSize(40,80);
    panel.add(picLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(title,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(button);
    add(buttonPanel);
    add(panel); 

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            OrderMainPage order = new OrderMainPage();

        }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        MainMenu main = new MainMenu();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("898 Food Ordering System");
        frame.add(main);
//      frame.setSize(120,130);
        frame.pack(); // size
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // place frame in center
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try a vertical Box or Boxlayout instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use BoxedLayout in place of FrameLayout :

```
    import java.awt.*;  
    import javax.swing.*;  
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import javax.imageio.*;

    class MainMenu extends Frame {  
    JLabel picLabel,title;
    JButton button;


     public MainMenu () { 
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    try{
       BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\seng\\workspace\\FoodOrderingSystem\\ramen-noodles.png"));

       Image scaled = myPicture.getScaledInstance(170,170,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
       picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaled));}catch(Exception e){}
       title = new JLabel("898 Food Restaurant"); 
       title.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD,18));
       title.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
       button = new JButton("Order Food Now >>");
       panel.add(picLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       panel.add(title,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
       buttonPanel.add(button);
       add(panel); 
    add(buttonPanel);
       setLayout (new BoxLayout (this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  
       setSize(400,400);  
       setVisible(true);  
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        MainMenu main = new MainMenu(); 
    }  
    }
```

Comment: BoxLayout cannot be shared

Comment: Change to `setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` and it solved.

Comment: How can I adjust the place for button and JLabel ?

Answer (score 2):

Each JComponent such as JPanel can only have one layout manager at a time. But since JComponents can be nested you can have different layout managers in your JFrame. Usually that is how you create complex layouts.

Now for your question about button placement. The setLocation won't do anything since your button is in JPanel and it by default uses FlowLayout that ignores location attribute. First step is to set buttonPanel layout to null. But that still might not be enough since the buttonPanel is positioned by another flow layout that will set it's bounds not within the location coordinates of the nested button.
You can always see your JPanel bounds by setting it's background to a different color.

My advice to always try to position your components using layout managers and avoid absolute positioning.